# No default folder in the User data folder anymore

Tags: windows, google-chrome

My sister accidentally remvoed my Google account from my computer and when I relogged in, a lot of data which was not saved in the cloud but in the google folder was lost.
There was a lot of data in some extensions, things that I've been working for years.
I've been so stupid not to back it up. I really need some help, some hope.
 If there is anyone know anything about, please share.
I especially saved my sessions in a google extension called Session Buddy and it was stored in UserData/Default but now there is no default folder anymore, only an empty and useless profile 3 folder.
Edit: This is what my Sister did
[image]
She clicked to remove the person, when I tried to readd my account, all the extension start to reinstall and my data was lost

Comment: When you say you remove the Google account from your account.  Are you talking about the Google Sync client or something else?  Edit your question.  Be as specific as possible if you want an answer to your question.

Comment: Aren't the data still available online for example on Google Drive?

Comment: No there's nothing on drive, and I posted a photo of what I mean by removed